# Routing on Vue with SSR and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, frontend, vue-router, server-side-rendering

I am learning Vue and got stuck trying setup it as full front-end with Laravel, on my scenario I already have made an personal blog for test using Laravel with Blade engine and some components of Vue and seems work fine.

I am trying get on next level, removing Blade and letting Laravel as API backend and setup Vue as full front end with SSR, the basic setup works, I mean I can call Vue, render it using SSR with node or PHPv8, the problem I am having is on route systems, thinking as blade way I can't archive same result, on blade I use an default layout as master and import it for every post, page, blog, etc...

Example:

> resources/views/layouts/master.blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

    <head>
        @include('partials._head')
    </head>

    @if(View::hasSection('body')) {{-- Load Custom Body --}}
        <body @section('body')>
    @else
        <body>
    @endif

        @yield('content')

        @include ('partials._javascripts')

        @section('scripts')
    </body>

</html>
```

So I call a dynamic head per page / post, a dynamic content, an basic javascripts (bootstrap, vue, fontawesome, etc...) and custom 'scripts' per page / posts.

Using the librarie:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering

I can get SSR working with node or PHPv8, but the vue-route never call the desired page, my setup is:

> resources/assets/js/app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './layouts/App';
import axios from 'axios';
import store from './store';
import router from './router';
import navbar from './components/navbar';
import posts from './components/posts';
import sidebar from './components/sidebar';
import footer from './components/footer';
import BlogIndex from './views/blog/BlogIndex';



export default new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    navbar,
    posts,
    sidebar,
    footer,
    BlogIndex,
    render: h => h(App),
});

resources/assets/js/entry-client.js

import app from './app';

app.$mount('#app');

resources/assets/js/entry-server.js

import app from './app';
import renderVueComponentToString from 'vue-server-renderer/basic';

app.$router.push(context.url);

renderVueComponentToString(app, (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
    dispatch(html);
});
```

> resources/assets/js/router.js

```
// router.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from './components/Home';
import BlogIndex from './views/blog/BlogIndex';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home },
    { path: '/blog', name: 'blog', component: BlogIndex },
];

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
});
```

> resources/assets/js/store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import uniq from 'lodash/uniq';
import Vuex, { Store } from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Store({
    state: {
    },

    getters: {
    },

    mutations: {
    },
});
```

> resources/assets/js/views/blog/BlogIndex.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <navbar></navbar>
        <posts></posts>
        <sidebar></sidebar>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</template>



<script>

    export default {
        name: "BlogIndex",
        components: {
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

> app/Http/Controllers/VueSSRController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

class VueSSRController extends Controller
{

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return view('layouts.vue');
    }

}
```

> resources/views/layouts/vue.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

    <head>
        @section('extrajavascripts'){{ asset('js/scripts.min.js') }}@endsection
        @include('partials._head')
    </head>

    @if(View::hasSection('body')) {{-- Load Custom Body --}}
    <body @section('body')>
    @else
    <body>
    @endif

        {{-- Begin of Vue SSR --}}
        {!! ssr('resources/assets/js/server_bundle.min.js')
            // Share the packages with the server script through context
            //->context('packages', $packages)
            // If ssr fails, we need a container to render the app client-side
            ->fallback('<div id="app"></div>')
            ->render() !!}
        {{-- End of Vue SSR --}}

        @include ('partials._javascripts')

        @section('scripts')
        @show

    </body>

</html>
```

> /resources/assets/js/layouts/App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id ="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "App",
        data() {
            return {
                message: 'SSR working.'
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

So SSR works fine, the problem is the resources/assets/js/router.js is not loading the resources/assets/js/views/blog/BlogIndex.vue, the url/blog works, but the component rendered is always the /resources/assets/js/layouts/App.vue.

Someone would point what I am missing setup please?

Thanks in advice!!!

Comment: I was also set up this on my local system. I am curious to know what did you write inside the web.php i.e routes.

Comment: @SachinKumar Unfortunately I had to abandon this setup as it was time consuming, in the end I ended up creating a subdomain for the laravel example api.website.com and working directly with Nuxt in the main domain website.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place `<router-view></router-view>` where you want the router to load. I think in your case its below `{{message}}` in App.vue

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!

You right, that started render the correct views.

That message is only for debug, looking for the tag data-server-rendered="true" on source.